# Why can't I open a file in priv/static in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If this file exists and is accessible from my Phoenix application:

```
https://localhost:4000/csvs/test3.csv?v=63637241208
```

i.e., if I can make a link to and download it from the application, why can't I use `File.open!(https://localhost:4000/csvs/test3.csv?v=63637241208)` to read it?

All I get is a `could not read file` error despite it existing. What's going on?

Comment: Did you pass the URL to `File.open!`? `File.open!` accepts a file path, not a URL. You can do `File.open!("priv/static/csvs/test3.csv")` if that file really is in that folder.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. Pretty simple, ha. I should delete this question.